# How to close all the windows when Mainwindow closes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am working on WPF. There is Mainwindow which opens as application starts. There are two buttons within this window. Each open a new window. e.g There are Add and update buttons. Add button opens a Add-Item window on its click event call and similarly update opens it's window "Update-Item". 
If i close  Mainwindow these two windows "Add-Item" and "Update-Item" remains open. I want that if i close Mainwindow, these other two windows should also close with it.

```
app.current.shutdown
```

app.current.shutdown is used mostly. My Question is: Where i have to post this code line in my program, in mainwindow or in App.config. Should i have to call any event or function in it's response too?

Answer (score 13):

You can also set ShutdownMode in the App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 11):

Set `Application.MainWindow` to the instance of your main window and make sure the `Application.ShutdownMode` is `OnMainWindowClose`.

Also if you do not want the whole application to shut down: Make the `MainWindow` the [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) of the child windows. (This has other side effects)

Comment: Where i have to set this? @H.B

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh: Doesn't really matter, i would do it in `Application.OnStartup` in the `App` class. (Ditch `StartupUri`, create the window manually, assign it)

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution is to set the `Owner` property of each of the sub-windows to your main window.  That way, any window action performed on your main window is also performed on all of the other windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since in the first glance it's quite hard to figure out the right way of doing what our friends advised I proceed with a little **example (best practice) code**.

This is what *Josh Smith* shows how your **App.xaml.cs** should look like.

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static App()
        {
            // Ensure the current culture passed into bindings is the OS culture.
            // By default, WPF uses en-US as the culture, regardless of the system settings.
            //
            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
              typeof(FrameworkElement),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var window = new MainWindow();

            // To ensure all the other Views of a type Window get closed properly.
            ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;

            // Create the ViewModel which the main window binds.
            var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

            // When the ViewModel asks to be closed,
            // close the window.
            EventHandler handler = null;
            handler = delegate
            {
                viewModel.RequestClose -= handler;
                window.Close();
            };
            viewModel.RequestClose += handler;

            // Allow all controls in the window to bind to the ViewModel by
            // setting the DataContext, which propagates down the element tree.
            window.DataContext = viewModel;
            window.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Again, at the end of the day, it's up to you how you would want to layout your MVVM application.